# SQL query returning less than or equal to instead of less than?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server management Studio I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @payo25 float
SET @payo25  = 7.2

SELECT first_name, surname, hourly_rate
FROM table1
WHERE hourly_rate < @payo25
```

This query returns:

```
Jane Smith   7.2
Fred Bloggs  4.9
```

I thought `<` meant less than, not less than or equal to?

Any ideas?

Comment: Well... it's a float... so... What is the field type of `hourly_rate`? What value do you get when you `SELECT hourly_rate FROM table1 WHERE firstname = 'Jane' and surname = 'Smith';`?

Comment: What datatype is `hourly_rate`?

Comment: You really should consider using an exact numeric datatype instead of float which is an approximate. It will probably work but not every value can be expressed accurately using float.

Comment: hourly_rate is datatype real

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: thanks, I changed the dataype for the variable to real and it works properly now

Comment: No, don't do that. Change them both to `DECIMAL`!

Comment: Changing from float to real is not actually a change. The real dataype is a synonym for float(24). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

Comment: Go for it, @JNevill

Comment: Learn more about FLOATs, and then start using DECIMAL or MONEY instead.

Comment: lol @RubensFarias. Done and done. Feel free to edit or comment to clean up my attempt at a layman's explaination. I was thinking "<grunt> Float bad. Real, good <grunt>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats are great for storing really big numbers where the trade off in precision is worth it to be able to store the really big number. If you aren't working with really big numbers, then use a more precise numeric data type like `real` or `decimal` or what have you.

What you'll find if you store `7.2` as a float, is that the actual number stored is something more like `7.20000000000000000000003`. So, when you compare it to `7.2` you get back the strange result that your float 7.2 is greater than your real 7.2.

Comment: lovely and clear, thank you.  I went for both reals, good SQL in my cave